# How to extract text using delimiters when some delimiters missing

Tags: r

I am trying to extract text according to the headers in a semi-structured text document.

**Input**

```
Column<-"Order:1223442 Subject:History Name Bilbo Johnson Grade: Bad Report: Need to complete Conclusion: Dud"
```

**The output here is**

```
Order     Subject Name           Grade  Report           Conclusion
1223442   History Bilbo Johnson   Bad   Need to complete  Dud
```

I can achieve this with the following (messy but it works) function:

```
dataframeIn<-data.frame(Column,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
delim<-c("Order","Subject","Name","Grade","Report","Conclusion")


Extractor <- function(dataframeIn, Column, delim) {
  dataframeInForLater<-dataframeIn
  ColumnForLater<-Column
  Column <- rlang::sym(Column)
  dataframeIn <- data.frame(dataframeIn)
  dataframeIn<-dataframeIn %>%
    tidyr::separate(!!Column, into = c("added_name",delim),
                                          sep = paste(delim, collapse = "|"),
                    extra = "drop", fill = "right")
  names(dataframeIn) <- gsub(".", "", names(dataframeIn), fixed = TRUE)

  dataframeIn<-data.frame(dataframeIn)
  #Add the original column back in so have the original reference
  dataframeIn<-cbind(dataframeInForLater[,ColumnForLater],dataframeIn)
  dataframeIn<-data.frame(dataframeIn)
  return(dataframeIn)
}

Extractor(dataframeIn, "Column", delim)
```

However, sometimes the delimiters are missing eg

```
Order:1223442 Subject:History Name Bilbo Johnson Grade: Bad Conclusion: Dud
```

In which case the desired output is

```
Order     Subject Name           Grade  Conclusion
1223442   History Bilbo Johnson   Bad    Dud
```

but the actual output becomes:

```
 Order   Subject            Name   Grade Report Conclusion
:1223442  :History   Bilbo Johnson  : Bad    : Dud       <NA>
```

How can I account for missing delimiters although they are in the same order (including delimiters that are missing in the middle of the text as well as the end as in the example above) ?

Comment: There is no colon after `Name`. Is that always a possibility or a typo?

Comment: @JuliusVainora yes the colon is sometimes missing so can't rely on it for a split unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

We may do the following (it's only text extraction, I leave constructing the output for you):

```
library(stringr)
Extractor <- function(x, delim) {
  pattern <- paste0(delim, ":{0,1}(.*?)(", paste(c(delim, "$"), collapse = "|"), ")")
  trimws(str_match(x, pattern)[, 2])
}
Extractor(Column1, delim)
# [1] "1223442"          "History"          "Bilbo Johnson"    "Bad"              "Need to complete" "Dud"
Extractor(Column2, delim)
# [1] "1223442"       "History"       "Bilbo Johnson" "Bad"           NA              "Dud"
Column3 <- "Subject:History Name Bilbo Johnson"
Extractor(Column3, delim)
# [1] NA              "History"       "Bilbo Johnson" NA              NA              NA
```

Since we have `NA`'s it's clear what delimiters were missing and what weren't.

The way it works in your case is that we have a series of patterns

```
pattern
# [1] "Order:{0,1}(.*?)(Order|Subject|Name|Grade|Report|Conclusion|$)"     
# [2] "Subject:{0,1}(.*?)(Order|Subject|Name|Grade|Report|Conclusion|$)"   
# [3] "Name:{0,1}(.*?)(Order|Subject|Name|Grade|Report|Conclusion|$)"      
# [4] "Grade:{0,1}(.*?)(Order|Subject|Name|Grade|Report|Conclusion|$)"     
# [5] "Report:{0,1}(.*?)(Order|Subject|Name|Grade|Report|Conclusion|$)"    
# [6] "Conclusion:{0,1}(.*?)(Order|Subject|Name|Grade|Report|Conclusion|$)"
```

Then `str_match` nice extracts the `(.*?)` part to the second output columns and we get rid of any spaces with `trimws`. Ah and we use lazy matching in `(.*?)` as not to match too much.